# Is this an undergraduate-level proof of conservation of energy, or an arbitrary manipulation of symbols that happens to give the right answer?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

This is a slightly farcical question, for which I apologise.

An undergraduate tutee of mine was faced with the following problem:

Q. A particle of mass $m$ moving along a line is subject to a force $F(x) = −dV /dx.$ Show that the energy $E =\frac{1}{2}mv^2+V(x)$ is constant.

Here is his answer.

A. We're given $F(x)=-dV/dx.$ Now $F=ma$, so $m\ddot{x}=-dV/dx .$

Next observe $\ddot{x}=\frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}=\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}\dot{x}$.

Hence $m\dot{x}\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx} = -dV/dx$, and integrating wrt $x$ we get $\frac12m\dot{x}^2 + V(x)=C$ a constant.

Is that a proof? On some formal level it looks fine to me. However an applied mathematician friend of mine (I'm a pure mathematiaian) objected that the UG had only proved that the energy was constant independent of $x$, rather than independent of $t$. I have no idea what that even means, on some level. On the other hand whilst I'm completely happy with the formal aspects of the argument, I have this uncomfortable feeling that if I were pressed to define $\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$ I would go for something like "change in $\dot{x}$ divided by change in $x$ and then take the limit" and if then someone observed that if the particle were stationary and $V$ were constant then $x$ wouldn't actually be changing so what does it even mean to change it, I think I'd be beginning to feel uncomfortable. The bottom line was that the marker didn't like it, because they claimed that something like $d(\dot{x})/dx$ was meaningless, and didn't give him any marks. I want to argue that usually it's meaningful but on the other hand...what am I saying here. I think I'm saying that part of me wants to resort to arguing that this proof is supposed to be applying to some space of potentials $V$, which are supposed to be at the very least continuous, so perhaps we could attempt to put some extra structure on the space of all potentials (e.g. restrict to $x$ in some closed and bounded interval and put some $L^2$ norm on it or something) and the potentials for which the argument seems a bit vague are some small subset of this space and so by continuity we should be fine. On the other hand this incident simply brings flooding back all the memories of the struggles I had doing applied mathematics when I was an undergraduate myself, when I would just try and answer the questions by formally manipulating the symbols and hoping that what I did would be bought by the people marking the questions.

Presumably there are people out there that have a sufficiently rigorous way of thinking about this sort of question that they can say for sure whether this argument actually deserves any marks? Is it really an argument that "isn't quite rigorous but can be made rigorous using a standard technique"? Or is it fine? Or, heaven forfend, is it a question for which different people might have different opinions??

Comment: My two cents: $x$ $\dot{x}$ etc. are (by assumption) single-valued functions of $t$.  $\dot{x}$ is not a single-valued function of $x$ for general paths, so $d\dot{x}/dx$ is meaningless.

Comment: @Rhys, but here we're assuming that $x(t)$ is precisely the trajectory of a particle, so I'm not clear what you mean by $\dot{x}$ not being single-valued.

Comment: The particle could pass back and forth over the same point many times, with many different velocities.  If we assume, a priori, that energy is conserved, then this velocity is determined up to a sign (in 1D), but that is circular.

Comment: Ah, that is a great point, I see now that I missed that. So our argument only works to show conservation of energy between critical points, so somehow there must be a way to extend the argument past the "horizon" where $\dot{x} = 0$.

Comment: Oh. Actually, I see how to fix it now. The issue is that integrating over $x$ isn't exactly well defined unless you treat it as a contour integral over the path of $x(t)$, which can be written as a sum of pieces, on each of which $x(t)$ is monotone.

Comment: I have now found two respectable mathematicians in my department, one of whom claims the solution deserves full marks and the other one claims that it does not. My conclusion is that I finally now realise why I struggled with applied mathematics -- unlike pure mathematics at this level it still seems to be the case that whether or not an answer is correct is a matter of opinion!

Comment: @Rhys: Consider the equation $x^2+y^2=7$. Would you be happy to say that $2xdx+2ydy=0$? Would you be happy to say that $dy/dx=-x/y$? I am absolutely convinced that on some level that I can make completely rigorous, the assertion $dy/dx=-x/y$ is true -- I could talk about modules of Kaehler differentials in algebraic geometry, for example. However $y$ is not a function of $x$. Hence I've now decided that I don't buy your objection raised in the first comment. I am genuinely confused.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a little old(but could prove useful later) but a proof I used whilst completing my undergrad in the physics dept was
1) multiply both sides by the velocity
$$
m\ddot{x}\dot{x}=-\frac{dV}{dx}\dot{x}
$$

Then pull out the time derivative to yield

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}=-\frac{dV}{dt}
$$
The rhs is just reverse of the chain rule.
Pulling everything to the left hand side, and subbing in v for the velocity we find

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{mv^2}{2}+V(x)\right]=0
$$

This leads to the conclusion that the energy in the system(kinetic + potential) I.e the terms in the brackets are independent of time and therefore constant or conservative.

You can also use this trick in solving the linear pendulum problem.

Comment: Sure -- the issue is not proving the assertion, the issue is deciding whether the argument I give in the original question is a valid proof or not.

Comment: I will not argue that the original question was about how valid the proof was. However, I defend that that solution I gave should be clear so that of someone wanted to see how an elegant proof should be for the 'original' question. I don't see why it was a problem ? But I respect that, this is your question and not mine, so I can remove it if you want?

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Adding my \$.02 : I think that both the original question and this answer suffer from the problem that they ignore the case $\dot{x}=0$. When $\dot{x}\neq 0$, $\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$ is well defined, I'd argue in the same intuitive sense that $\int f(t) d(x(t))$ is defined. When $\dot{x}=0$, it suffices that $\frac{mv^2}{2}+V(x(t))$ is *differentiable* wrt t. So I think the problem comes down to adding a special case when $\dot{x}=0$, and after that the answer should be acceptable by almost all standards!

Answer (score 2):

This proof appears valid to me. The justification of $\ddot{x} = \dot{x} \tfrac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$ via chain rule is acceptable mathematically, and even though the equations involved are supposed to have physical meaning, there is no need to explain what $\tfrac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$ means. From a physical level, what we have shown is that *Work*, which is defined as the change in kinetic energy, can be expressed as
$$ W = \Delta K = \int F \, dx$$
Then, since $F = -dV/dx$, then we have precisely shown that $\Delta K = - \Delta V$, so the total mechanical energy $K + V$ is constant.

*Concerning the discussion above*: While the above formally works, the main issue is that $\tfrac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$ may not be well defined. The crux of the problem is that the quantity
$$W = \int m\ddot{x} \, dx(t)$$
is in fact a line integral along the path of $x(t)$. If $t_0$ and $t_{k+1}$ are the initial and final times, and $t_1, \ldots, t_k$ are times at $\dot{x}$ changes sign, then we can turn the above into a sum of ordinary integrals against a Stieltjes measure (e.g. the variable we're integrating against is monotone), and so we have
$$ W = \sum_{i=0}^k \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} m \ddot{x} \, dx = \sum_{i=0}^k \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} m \ddot{x} \frac{dx}{dt} \, dt = \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \frac{1}{2} m\frac{d}{dt} \left[\dot{x}^2 \right]\, dt = \Delta \left( \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2\right)$$

Comment: What does it mean, on a formal level, for $\dot{x}$ to change sign? I am thinking of a continuous function which one might argue changes sign on the Cantor set (for some definition of "changes sign") and that is a long way from "$t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k$". Does this worry you, or can you rule it out, or are your methods robust enough not to care? I'm pretty sure the UG will only recently have seen a rigorous definition of Riemann integral at this point in his education ;-)

Comment: Kevin, $x(t)$ is defined as the solution of a differential equation, so such perverse functions won't arise.

Comment: @Rhys: I don't believe your last comment. $x$ is defined as the solution to a differential equation which mentions a function $V$ about which we know nothing other than the implicit assertion that it's continuously differentiable.

Comment: Okay, that's a fair point; I suppose some 'nice enough' conditions on $V$ are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The marker was absolutely wrong to argue that $\frac{d \dot{x}}{dx}$ is meaningless! It is the spacial rate of change of velocity, which is a perfectly well defined concept. If the velocity doesn't change at all then $\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$ is 0, for this to be true then there are no forces on the particle to accelerate it so the potential gradient must also be zero (so the potential must be constant through space). The equation for the potential gradient the student derived is correct and integration wrt x is perfectly valid for this one dimensional problem, and proves the conservation of energy of a particle moving through space. Since the particle energy is conserved at each space point it arrives at, the energy must also be conserved through time.

In the problem for motion in more than one dimension, integration wrt the space dimensions makes little sense-I think this is why some folk think the student was misguided in his approach.

Eg consider motion in 2 dimensions: If we have a potential V(x,y) then the force $F_x$ in the x direction is $$F_x= - \frac{\partial{V(x,y)}}{\partial{x}}.$$ Similarly for the y direction and $$dV = \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x}} dx + \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{y}} dy .$$ so $$- \frac{d{V}}{d{t}}= m (\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}.\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}.\frac{dy}{dt})= m(v_x \frac{dv_x}{dt}+v_y \frac{dv_y}{dt}) .$$ So integrate wrt time gives $$-V(x.y)=\frac{mv_x^2}{2}+\frac{mv_y^2}{2} + const.$$ So (Total KE + PE) = constant in time. It is also constant at each point in space along the path of the motion.